# Authenticate SAAS services with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cloud, dropbox, saas

Is it possible to authenticate Dropbox account in real-time using Active Directory? I mean not only one-time directory sync that can go out of sync very quickly but to be able to authenticate users in Dropbox using Active Directory in real-time.

Thanks

Comment: If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot authenticate DropBox users *directly* against Active Directory, you *could* achieve what would look exactly like this to the end-user by federating between Active Directory to DropBox using ADFS, and create a rule in ADFS which basically says, if user exists in Active Directory, let him access DropBox account.  This answer greatly simplifies the work and setup involved, but you get the idea.  Here's the exact step-by-step to do this, including screenshots:  [How do I connect Dropbox to AD FS 3.0 for single sign-on (SSO)?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/connect-adfs3-sso)